# How to get a file's name from FILE* struct in C

Tags: c, file

Is it possible to retrieve a file's name in C? If a file is created like the following:

```
     FILE *f = fopen ("foo.txt", "r");
```

And the "foo.txt" comes from a variable out of scope. Is there a way to retrieve it from the FILE struct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can't* in fact retrieve the file names from your `FILE` objects.

However, if the name being passed to `fopen` is important to you, and that variable is out of scope for whatever reason, you could always wrap a `FILE*` in a struct, ie.

```
struct file_with_name {
   FILE *f;
   char *name; /* OR char name[MAX] */
}
```

At least that's what I'd do but it depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: That's what I'll end up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, on many systems a filename is just a pointer to an inode. And if those filesystems support hard links, that means that there are multiple filenames per real file. Also, you can open a file and then remove the file in which case there wouldn't even be a filename, just a descriptor. For these reasons, you can't go from a file descriptor to a file name.

Answer (score 6):

Its not possible to get the filename out of a `FILE` handle. You should store the filename yourself if you later need to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Since `FILE` objects may be created from things that have no name associated with them (in particular, from a raw file descriptor with `fdopen()`), they do not always have a name to get.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it's not possible. The closest you can try, on Linux, is:

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fileno(f));
readlink(buf, buf, sizeof buf);
```

Reusing `buf` like that is horribly ugly, but as far as I can tell, it's legal and not undefined behavior per POSIX.